# Serial to USB, no ttyUSB0

Tags: raspbian, python, serial

I'm trying to open a Serial communication between a Raspberry Pi 3 (model B, running on Raspbian) and a device (a traffic counter to be precise).

I've a USB to Serial cable, using the rs232 standard. (so I'm not using the GPIO)

My goal is to be able to open a serial communication between this device and my rpi3 using python and the pyserial library.

(on windows everything works fine, I open a COMx port and I can then communicate with the device)

My problem:
When I plug my Serial to USB cable, the rpi3 don't even create a `ttyUSB0` device. What is going on ? How could I open a serial communication in python ?

```
dmesg -w

[ 3482.730866] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[ 3482.891077] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=9bf0
[ 3482.891093] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3482.891102] usb 1-1.4: Product: TrafficCounter USB Adapter
[ 3482.891110] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TrafficCounter
[ 3482.891118] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: FTVNFDLZ
```

If I run a

```
glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
I obtain:
['/dev/ttyS0', '/dev/ttyAMA0', '/dev/ttyprintk']
```

And I can see my device with lsusb:

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0403:9bf0 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I managed to have ttyUSB appear through raspi-config.

You just have to go to Interfaces Settings and say you want the serial port activated.

I hope it will help :)

Comment: Yes, that's good for me as well. I'm using an SMS dongle, `lsusb` gave a good result but the port wouldn't open. Did a reboot after port activation and `/dev/ttyUSB0` is usable.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttyAMA0` are inbuilt UARTS.

NOT all USB devices/drivers are "tty".

Unplug the device, list `/dev` then plug in and see what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for your answers, unfortunately that did not resolve my problem.

I guess that ftdi_sio module do not support anymore the "vendor" and "product" attribute. So

`modprobe ftdi_sio vendor=0x0403 product = 0x9bf0`

Didn't work for me.

What worked:

I'v added my vendorid and productid in `/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id`

`sudo nano /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id`

and then i just add:

`0403 9bf0`

How to automate this process --> [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67936/attaching-usb-serial-device-with-custom-pid-to-ttyusb0-on-embedded/165845)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already solved the problem, but for the reference, I use the following script to debug problems on USB bus:

```
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
    )
done
```

Sample output:

```
/dev/input/event0 - 040b_GiGa_HiD
/dev/ttyUSB0 - 1a86_USB2.0-Serial
/dev/ttyACM0 - Arduino__www.arduino.cc
/dev/sdb - WD_Elements_2620
/dev/sdb1 - WD_Elements_2620
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the ftdi-sio module manually with modprobe and specifying vendor and product id, or follow the guidelines in their manual at

https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_101_Customising_FTDI_VID_PID_In_Linux(FT_000081).pdf

Afterwards, you'll have a /dev/ttyUSBn.